# Documentum Inbox notification deletion

Tags: dql, documentum6.5

I need to delete a user inbox notification of particular r_object_id:

I tried  to  delete using DQL: dm_queue_item where r_object_id ='0000000"

But i think its wrong please let me know what will be the corrects syntax

Answer (score 0):

You first get the `object_id`, then run the api commands `acquire,c,object_id` and then `complete,c,object_id`. It works if there´s no action to be executed.

Comment: The result will be something like this: API>acquire,1b11b6f48400d011
...
Error processing command:DfException:: THREAD: http-7080-1; MSG: [DM_API_E_BADID]error:  "Bad ID given: 0000000000000000"; ERRORCODE: 100; NEXT: null
API>acquire,c,1b11b6f48400d011
...
Error processing command:DfException:: THREAD: http-7080-1; MSG: [DM_DFC_E_TYPE_MISMATCH_ADD]error:  "Type mismatch. Expected type "IDfWorkitem"; got type "com.documentum.fc.client.DfQueueItem___PROXY"."; ERRORCODE: 221; NEXT: null
API>execute acquire c
...
This is not a valid API command.